# Know all the Checked item at when I press "ok" button SWING

Tags: java, jquery, swing, jbutton, jcheckbox

When I click ok button it should print all the checked items. Here is what I tried.

I tried the following code, but its not working.

```
public class FilePermission extends JPanel implements ItemListener {

static String[] videoAvailable = new String[25];
static int j = 0;
JCheckBox[] file_boxes = new JCheckBox[25];
JButton button;
StringBuffer choices;
JLabel pictureLabel;
//static int j = 0;

public FilePermission() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    //Create the check boxes.
    for (int i = 0; i < videoAvailable.length; i++) {
        if (videoAvailable[i] != null) {
            file_boxes[i] = new JCheckBox(videoAvailable[i]);
            file_boxes[i].addItemListener(this);
            checkPanel.add(file_boxes[i]);
        }
    }
    button = new JButton("ok");
    //Register a listener for the check boxes.
    button.addItemListener(this);
    //Indicates what's on the geek.
    //Set up the picture label
    pictureLabel = new JLabel();
    pictureLabel.setFont(pictureLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
    //Put the check boxes in a column in a panel

    checkPanel.add(button);

    add(checkPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    add(pictureLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
}

/** Listens to the check boxes. */
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < videoAvailable.length; i++) {
        if (videoAvailable[i] != null) {
            if (file_boxes[i].isSelected()) {
                System.out.println(file_boxes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (button.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println(button);
    }
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBoxDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new FilePermission();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File directory = new File("D:\\ims\\");
    parseDir(directory);

    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
  }
```

There methods are invoked from the main method of the java class. I would like to answer if you didn't understand.

Comment: Will you please provide ActionListener's implementation?

Comment: Can you post all of your code please? Where is your listener?

Comment: I posted all my code. I think I don't have any method called action listner.

Comment: The parseDir method is missing and you're not setting the videoAvailable array anywhere.  This, in turn, is causing your GUI to just create the ok button and no check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment "button.addItemListener(this);".
Or use ActionListener for OK Button.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer.  It is as follows:

```
public class FilePermission extends JPanel implements ItemListener {

static String[] videoAvailable = new String[25];
static int j = 0;
JCheckBox[] file_boxes = new JCheckBox[25];
JButton button;
StringBuffer choices;
JLabel pictureLabel;
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBoxDemo");

//static int j = 0;

public FilePermission() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    //Create the check boxes.
    for (int i = 0; i < videoAvailable.length; i++) {
        if (videoAvailable[i] != null) {
            file_boxes[i] = new JCheckBox(videoAvailable[i]);
            file_boxes[i].addItemListener(this);
            checkPanel.add(file_boxes[i]);
        }
    }
    button = new JButton("ok");
    //Register a listener for the check boxes.
    button.addItemListener(this);
    //Indicates what's on the geek.
    //Set up the picture label
    pictureLabel = new JLabel();
    pictureLabel.setFont(pictureLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
    //Put the check boxes in a column in a panel

    checkPanel.add(button);

    add(checkPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    add(pictureLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < videoAvailable.length; i++) {
        if (videoAvailable[i] != null) {
            if (file_boxes[i].isSelected()) {
                System.out.println(videoAvailable[i]);
            }
        }
    }
                     frame.dispose();

            }
    });
}

/** Listens to the check boxes. */
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < videoAvailable.length; i++) {
        if (videoAvailable[i] != null) {
            if (file_boxes[i].isSelected()) {
                System.out.println(file_boxes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (button.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println(button);
    }
}


/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new FilePermission();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File directory = new File("D:\\ims\\");
    parseDir(directory);

    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
   }

public static void parseDir(File dirPath) {
    try {
        File files[] = null;
        if (dirPath.isDirectory()) {
            files = dirPath.listFiles();

            for (File dirFiles : files) {

                if (dirFiles.isDirectory()) {
                    parseDir(dirFiles);
                } else {
                    if (dirFiles.getName().endsWith(".mkv")) {

                        videoAvailable[j] = dirFiles.getName();
                        j++;

                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (dirPath.getName().endsWith(".mkv")) {
                videoAvailable[j] = dirPath.getName();
                j++;
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 }
```